# How do I make use of Chrome's heap profiler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

How do I make use of Chrome's heap profiler?  When I expand a tree, what do the children objects represent?  What is the count column a count of exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial#profiles)'s a short tutorial.

The children are objects that contain/reference the parent object. For example, if you have a class `List` and it contains an array of items you get his:

String
--Array
----List

String, Array and List are the Constructors used to create the respective object.

So you might have 50 Strings if you have 5 lists with 10 items each.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH7sJbyXHuk#t=36m40s) explains things in a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Profiles Docs](https://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html) or more specifically the [Heap-Profiling Docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling.html) helped me a lot.